# Using MMDetection with custom dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I want to learn how to use the MMdetection library to learn how to detect numbers in images. The [SVHN dataset](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/) was chosen as the training sample. It presents data in .mat format.

Following the guide on the [official page](https://mmdetection.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/customize_dataset.html) I created an annotation.txt file

```
#
1.png
741 350
1
43 7 19 30 5 
#
2.png
199 83
3
99 5 14 23 2 
114 8 8 23 1 
121 6 12 23 0 
...
```

After that, I made a special class handler for the dataset

```
@DATASETS.register_module()
class MyDataset(CustomDataset):
    CLASSES = ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')

    def load_annotations(self, ann_file):
        ann_list = mmcv.list_from_file(ann_file)

        data_infos = []
        for i, ann_line in enumerate(ann_list):
            if ann_line != '#':
                continue

            img_shape = ann_list[i + 2].split(' ')
            width = int(img_shape[0])
            height = int(img_shape[1])
            bbox_number = int(ann_list[i + 3])

            bboxes = []
            labels = []
            for anns in ann_list[i + 4:i + 4 + bbox_number]:
                anns = anns.strip().split(' ')
                bboxes.append([float(ann) for ann in anns[:4]])
                labels.append(int(anns[4]))

            data_infos.append(
                dict(
                    filename=ann_list[i + 1],
                    width=width,
                    height=height,
                    ann=dict(
                        bboxes=np.array(bboxes).astype(np.float32),
                        labels=np.array(labels).astype(np.int64))
                ))

        return data_infos

    def get_ann_info(self, idx):
        return self.data_infos[idx]['ann']
```

And finally created my config in the appropriate folder

```
_base_ = '../mask_rcnn/mask_rcnn_r50_caffe_fpn_mstrain-poly_1x_coco.py'

model = dict(
    roi_head=dict(
        bbox_head=dict(num_classes=10)))

img_norm_cfg = dict(
    mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53], std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375], to_rgb=True)

train_pipeline = [
    dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
    dict(type='LoadAnnotations', with_bbox=True, with_mask=False),
    dict(
        type='Resize',
        img_scale=[(1333, 640), (1333, 672), (1333, 704), (1333, 736),
                   (1333, 768), (1333, 800)],
        multiscale_mode="value",
        keep_ratio=True),
    dict(type='RandomFlip', flip_ratio=0.5),
    dict(type='Normalize', **img_norm_cfg),
    dict(type='Pad', size_divisor=32),
    dict(type='DefaultFormatBundle'),
    dict(type='Collect', keys=['img', 'gt_bboxes', 'gt_labels']),
]

test_pipeline = [
    dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
    dict(
        type='MultiScaleFlipAug',
        img_scale=(1333, 800),
        flip=False,
        transforms=[
            dict(type='Resize', keep_ratio=True),
            dict(type='RandomFlip'),
            dict(type='Normalize', **img_norm_cfg),
            dict(type='Pad', size_divisor=32),
            dict(type='ImageToTensor', keys=['img']),
            dict(type='Collect', keys=['img']),
        ])
]

dataset_type = 'COCODataset'
classes = ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',)
data = dict(
    train=dict(
        img_prefix='../dataset/train/',
        type='MyDataset',
        ann_file='../annotation_train.txt',
        pipeline=train_pipeline),
    val=dict(
        img_prefix='../dataset/test/',
        type='MyDataset',
        ann_file='../annotation_test.txt',
        pipeline=test_pipeline),
    test=dict(
        img_prefix='../dataset/test/',
        type='MyDataset',
        ann_file='../annotation_test.txt',
        pipeline=test_pipeline))

load_from = 'checkpoints/mask_rcnn_r50_caffe_fpn_mstrain-poly_2x_coco_bbox_mAP-0.403__segm_mAP-0.365_20200504_231822-a75c98ce.pth'
```

But unfortunately I get an error that the number of classes should be equal to 80 and not 10. Please tell me how this can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For each config referenced in `_base_`, and each `_base_` that this config's `_base_` inherits from, you have to modify `num_classes` to your custom number.

It's a bit of an annoyance, but that's the way things have been designed in mmdetection.
https://mmdetection.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guides/config.html#reuse-variables-in-base-file